# Is the complexity of Caesar (shift) ciphers “n * n!”?

Tags: classical-cipher, complexity

Can we say that any shift cipher to be decrypted needs an algorithm of complexity “`n * n!`”? (where `n` is number of possible values. 26 in case of English language).

My reasoning related to reaching `n * n!` was as follows:

Take the word `BRAZIL` for example. We have 26 possibilities for `B`, 25 for `R, 24 for`A`, etc. Thus`O(n!)`. We also can have this 26 times, B was A now, but is a G in the next time, thus 26 which is`O(n)`hence`O(n * n!)`.

Comment: Probably not. What's $n$ anyway?

Comment: @fkraiem see updated question

Comment: Please note that "decryption" usually means an algorithm which knows the key. And knowing the key, you should be able to decrypt a text in O(length of text).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann good point !

Answer (score 5):

How on earth did you arrive at that formula?

You can break a Caesar cipher by calculating the result of applying all of the $n-1$ (i.e., 25) possible shifts to the ciphertext and picking the one that makes sense. The computational complexity is just $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

If you want to automate the process based on frequency analysis, the correlation step where you pick the most likely offset would perhaps have $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ complexity, but in practice you could probably achieve this by only considering a small subset of the most common letters. (For the English alphabet, E, T, A, I, O and N should suffice).

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer and included my reasoning. Can you please check and let me know where/how I got it wrong ?

Comment: @tony9099 In a Caesar shift cipher, every letter is shifted by the same offset. So there are just 25 possible keys to test. That's all. You appear to be thinking of a monoalphabetic substitution cipher, where any letter can be mapped to any other. Although this has a larger keyspace (26 factorial), the code can still be broken by frequency analysis with O(n^2) complexity. (Actually I don't understand the last bit where you say we "have this 26 times". What does that mean?)

Comment: Strictly speaking, wouldn't brute-force be $O(2^n)$ just like it is on every other scheme (because $n$ is the _length_ of the key, not number of possible keys)?

Comment: @cpast No. A **26-bit** key would give you a keyspace of 2^26 (64M) permutations. But a key that consists of a single number from 1 to 25 can only give you 25 permutations.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage EDIT: Never mind, I didn't notice the questions quirky definition of $n$.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage you are right. I think I was being lost between `complexity` and `number of possibilities (permutations)`. Two are different things. Since the offset is the same for all in the shift cipher (unlike as you said the substitution cipher) finding the offset is enough. By the way, what should I have written instead of the `n` to make the definition of the possibilities space correct. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you consider arbitrary permutations, you have $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ possibilities. That means, $O(n^2)$ is the correct complexity in big-O notation, but I don't understand why you need that at all, if you can provide the result as exact formula.

Caesar cipher contains  just a subset of $n$ possibilities, and therefore obviously $O(n)$.

Anyway, this doesn't cover algorithms like frequency analysis, which works both for the Caesar cipher and the general *simple substitution cipher*.